# Как записать следующий код Pascal в Python

Tags: python, pascal

[image]

Какое последнее значение i будет выведено на экран:

```
 FOR i=2 TO 40

 PRINT b+i,  i
```

Пытался записать данный код, но не могу понять причём тут переменная b

Comment: А мы то откуда можем знать, причём тут переменная `b`?

Comment: ваш паскаль подозрительно похож на бэйсик

Comment: так это бэйсик?

Comment: то есть код на бэйсике от 2 до 40 прибавляет какое-то b?

Comment: последнее значение i, будет 40. b -неважно какое

Comment: большое спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b = 0
for i in range(2, 41):
    print(b + i, i)
```